# Correct design of Colpitts oscillator

Tags: voltage, oscillator, common-emitter

I have been watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4bAfDu6F1k) video and when it is designing the colpitts oscillator it doesn't add a base resistor. I am thinking that is wrong because the BJT will saturate since the guy sets a base voltage 1/2VCC + VBE(0.7) to make the temperature dependent Vbe not important. So if we add a base resistor to the Collpits oscillator will that change something important (feedback fraction or the amplification of the signal ( in the  closed loop configuration ) ) .

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh0u8B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why don't we add another base resistor here?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWX0at.png)</sup>

Comment: Andy i am just asking why he doesn't add a base resistor since only with the emmitter resistor the BJT will saturate and we won't get the voltage we need at the base and how the addition of base resistor will affect the feedback fraction and the amplification in the closed loop configuration

Comment: What do you mean by "add a base resistor"? There are two connected to the base in the first images of that video you linked. Why add another one (and where would you add it)? Post a schematic that you feel lacks a base resistor and indicate on that schematic where you think it should go.

Comment: Andy mud is very clear.I have uploaded a new version the name of the resistors Rb1 and Rb2 are reversed but you get the point across.

Comment: It is absolutely not clear WHY do you think that such a resistor (Rb3) would be necessary. More than that, what is the block "LC oscillator"?

Comment: It won't work at all well with RB3 because there would be a significant phase change due to the BJT's miller capacitance and, what does it achieve? Nothing that I can see. The BJT won't saturate at all without RB3.

Comment: Thanks LvW for the time you put on the comment.

Comment: No problem - however, what is your answer to my question?

Comment: it is an LC oscillator made of a capacitive voltage divider and an inductor with some parasitic capacitance.

Comment: @CloneWars if you are done with this question now, there is a procedure for accepting the best answer. I mention this because you don't appear to be aware of that. [Take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this is done. Please also consider doing the same on earlier questions that have received a decent answer. It's not obligatory but, not doing it gets noticed and can lead to a lack of help in the future. Apart from that, you don't want to gain a reputation of being mean do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an equivalent input series resistance.  Why would you think you need more? hFE Re = Rin.

The concept of the Colpitts Osc shown here is to amplify AC current > 1 by series resonance in phase with output.  This would be a Series mode Crystal with low ESR and the Xtal is a RsCmLCp equivalent  circuit with C1,C2 added for tuning.

[Here I have simulated a 10MHz Colpitts Osc](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCCsCmC0YQOwDoBsYCciAclWUQCYsAGAqSKKEgKACcQBmSQkAFmyZfEM5PDAkh9JiTY9OjMSEKFx-VNiG0GbMKnCINajbPnhlNAO5dWHduvZ9jpmXIu77tAPIPwbcW1TiwHkP1oAJTdzHXANAPZ%20SkiSZEgaAHM3PRS2WJoAF1swXjdcvnAQeDRESDBEZkhIEmwtf2RcnCFILAw1VshzQWFVS1DLBFZ%20HpspHzzmVgL-Me5U8bt5GgBjHMnuCojwOEEGpqUyNo6MLr5kITBVnPqppf8d%20H5GRtJCSGw2aqIlNkQGy42MJbG4RIGDerAvwqCSwxYzEa0NYzBbSVIjXYBC61Fj4DzYRhaXIkDDnQFqaZ5GYo%20wQEgAHQAzoRkHVdmAmS93oRCadfIgyugmXFLv4mWBdowmfBGL5kFIwIxUBhTqhUIg2MLsXStUJ3rqCmoMIRFbUCcQSBEmahkGwaAB7KiMYY8YicNiNLwYEnmjDqEjMAGikY0IA) with an added series Rs=10 that you may adjust with your mouse-wheel to determine how much gain margin you have before it stops oscillating.  This is how you validate the oscillator gain stability margin for a given series crystal oscillator.

This is time-averaged if the transistor ratios are overdriven into cutoff of base current, or may be tuned for small Vbe variations and a better sinewave out.

Comment: Thanks Tony for the time you put on the answer but because you are a pro in electronics I can't follow you very easily

Answer (score 1):

> *I am thinking that is wrong because the BJT will saturate since the
> guy sets a base voltage 1/2VCC + VBE(0.7)*

You are stating that the base will be at roughly half Vcc so, if the collector is at full Vcc (which it is) then how can the BJT ever be in saturation?

Comment: Thanks Andy for the time you put on the answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about what BJT saturation is.  A BJT starts going into saturation when \$V_C = V_B\$, and is *really* saturated when \$V_{CB}\$ starts approaching a diode drop -- in other words, when the base-collector diode goes into forward conduction.

If the base voltage is held at about \$\frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$, then \$V_{CE}\$ will also be about \$\frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$, or a bit more.

As long as \$V_{CC}\$ is greater than a few volts, the base-collector diode will be well into the reverse-bias region.  The transistor won't be saturated in that case, and the common-collector amplifier circuit will work just fine as shown.

Comment: If I have a common emitter circuit without a base resistor and VCC is relative small then it will go to saturation because the voltage drop on the emitter resistor will have to be > VCC which is impossible.That is what I mean by saturation.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the time you put on the answer.

Comment: Why do you think that the voltage drop "on the emitter resistor will have to be >VCC" ? The current thtrough the transistor depends on the base voltage divider!

Comment: "That is what I mean by saturation" that's not what everyone else means by saturation.  It's a very well-defined term for bipolar junction transistors -- I suggest you adjust your terminology.